# PHP MYSQL Count a number of fields within a table using the date field

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i'm new to php and mysql and I wanted to create a code that checks the number of rows within a database for example:

```
id |userid| date      | amount
1  | 156  |2016-05-11 | 60.99
2  | 156  |2016-05-12 | 89.99
3  | 156  |2016-05-13 | 99.99
4  | 156  |2016-05-14 | 69.99
5  | 156  |2016-05-15 | 79.99
6  | 156  |2016-05-16 | 59.99
7  | 156  |2016-05-17 | 39.99
```

Is there a statement I can create which checks todays date and and depending on the month checks how many entries there are within the same month as the date and then adds the amounts together to give a sum at the end?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want to do this in MySQL only, or in MySQL and PHP? Would you want to use the two numbers separately?

Comment: what you need are (mysql) aggregate functions.

Comment: I'm guessing you have to use php and mysql because the amounts will have to be added using a loop. I get how to add the amounts together, I just want to figure out how to do the check to see how many dates within a certain month there are if for example there are 7 then add the amounts together.

Comment: Thanks Fred I'll give that a go

Comment: Thanks Frank that worked. if you want to add amounts together your best using aggregate Functions

Answer (score 0):

If u wanna get the number of rows from that table use `mysqli_num_rows()` function it will return number of rows from the results.  The function works only for SELECT and SHOW.